# How to graph $f(x)= \frac{1}{2} (e^x + e^{-x})$ without graphing app?

Tags: exponential-function, graphing-functions, piecewise-continuity

> The function $f$ is defined by $f(x)= \frac{1}{2} (e^x + e^{-x})$, $x \in \Re$.
> Show that $f$ has no inverse.

If I am to show that function $f$ has no inverse, I would graph function $f$ and show that it does not pass the horizontal-line test, as a horizontal line passing through the graph would have more than one intersection point.

The problem is, I am not sure how to graph $f(x)= \frac{1}{2} (e^x + e^{-x})$ without using a graphing application. I know how a $y=e^x$ graph looks like, but how do I combine $e^x + e^{-x}$?

I thought of using Piecewise function, but I do not know how to proceed.

[image]

Comment: Note that $f(x)=f(-x)$ so... ?

Comment: @DominikKutek it's a reflection on the y-axis....but how can I tell by looking at the function, how a graph looks like? if I don't use a graphing app

Comment: This (real) function is the hyperbolic cosine , and it is an even function. Thus it can't be injective and then it is non-invertible. If you insist in plotting it then care only about $\;x\ge 0\;$ .

Comment: It is easy to see that it's even, no need for graphing it. And because it isn't injective, then it cannot has inverse

Comment: Is it possible to use Piecewise function to graph this?

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{e^x}2=\frac12\;,\;\;\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{e^{-x}}2=\frac12$$

and then

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^x}2=\infty\;,\;\;\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{e^{-x}}2=0$$

And all this basically tells you what happens to the graph of the function for $\;x\ge0\;$.

If we add to this that the function is monotonically ascending since

$$f'(x)=\frac12\left(e^x-e^{-x}\right)=\frac{2^{2x}-1}{2e^x}>0\,,$$

Since the exponential is ascending and $\;e^{2x}>e^x\;$, you can see how the positive (and thus also the negative) branch of this function ascend pretty quickly to $\;\infty\;$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but can you edit some parts because I can't as the editing is less than 6 characters? added an equal sign for the second limit in the first row; edited typo in 'monotonically'; edited $f'(x)$ function in numerator part $e^{2x}$. Thank you

Comment: @gc3941d Thank you, edited.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) = \frac12(e^x + e^{-x}).$

$f''(x) = \frac12(e^x + e^{-x}) > \frac12(0+0)= 0$ for all $x$, i.e. $f(x)$ is strictly concave.

Also, as pointed out before, $f(x)$ is *even*: $f(x) = f(-x)$, and this means that the graph can be reflected in the $y-$axis. Concavity along with evenness of $f$ suggests that $f(0)$ is a minimum.

Let's confirm the stationary points of the graph for good measure. $f'(x) = 0 \implies e^x - e^{-x} = 0 \implies e^x = \frac{1}{e^x} \implies e^{2x} = 1 \implies 2x = 0 \implies x=0,$ so $(0,f(0)) = (0,1)$ is the only stationary point and it is a minimum because $f$ is concave.

Also, $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) = \lim_{x \to -\infty}f(x) = \infty $, but we are still not done, because we haven't shown that our graph doesn't have asymptotes. But $\lim_{x \to \infty}f'(x) = \lim_{x \to \infty}{ \left(e^x - e^{-x}\right)} = \infty,$ and $\lim_{x \to -\infty}f'(x) = \lim_{x \to -\infty}{ \left(e^x - e^{-x}\right)} = -\infty.$

And now we know what the graph looks like.